# Gaps in Unbounded Dependency Construction/ Immediate Subject

Tags: grammar

Excerpt from Pullum’s grammar book:

With immediate subjects we can have a gap in Type IB construction (with external antecedent) but not in type IA (with prenuclear antecedent).

Compare:

c. This is the copy [that [____ is defective].

d. This is the copy [which is defective].

e. Who signed the letter?

If I strictly follow the above rule and use a gap in the RC with external antecedent, I should assume that the below sentence (a) is correct, but it is not, whereas (b) sounds correct.

a.*I want a car [____ is safe].

b.  I want a car [that____ is safe].

1. I do not venture to doubt the rule stated by Pullum, but it seems to be incomplete. Should I assume that «we can have a gap in Type IB construction (with external antecedent) ****and subordinator – that»****
2. What if pronoun "which" is used as an anticedent of an immediate subject?
3. Could you please direct me to a specific rule or give some explanation as to when immediate subjects in RC can be extracted and realized by gap.

Thank you for any support!

Comment: Following the structure of the first two (c. and d.) only b. is right. Not a. It is types like: The car [that I saw] was blue. A car [that is safe] is best. The first has a action verb in the RC, and the second can be rewritten as: A safe car is best.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the precise reference, the quoted material is from CGEL pp. 1083–1084.

Comment: Incidentally, I highly recommend *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, 2nd edition, which is a textbook based on the CGEL framework. The exposition is streamlined and generally very clear.

Answer (score 1):

> a.**I want a car* [____ *is safe*].
>
> b. *I want a car* [*that____ is safe*].

In a non-*wh* relative where the gap is in subject position, "that" is not omissible and hence a. is ungrammatical.

You could instead have a *wh* relative:

> c. *I want a car* [*which is safe*].

Since the relative pronoun in c. is in subject position, a gap is not required. Note that "which" is not the antecedent but the relativised element that has "car" as antecedent.